# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.cell._writer'?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I am trying to build an exe file for the GUI that I created using python POyqt5. After completing the process, I try to launch the UI and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_3.py", line 14, in <module>
    import openpyxl
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module 
  File "openpyxl\___init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\workbook\____init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimode2_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimode2_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_write_only.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 23, in init openpyxl.worksheet._writer 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.cell._writer'
[13336] Failed to execute script 'main_3' due to unhandled exception!
```

I have openpyxl installed and I have also got it imported in my python script. Still, this error remains. Any leads on solving this will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should say what tool you are using to create the `.exe`. That isn't self-evident. But it is likely that your problem is what `pyinstaller` calls a "hidden import". If you are using `pyinstaller` then there is a very helpful section in the documentation called *When things go wrong*, and I suggest you work through that. If you are using something else then you'll need to consult that tool's documentation. In either case it involves telling the tool that it needs to include the imported module in the `.exe`, so that it can form part of the temporary Python installation the `.exe` creates.

Comment: Also, pyinstaller creates a standalone exe that should only use the packages bundled with it, so the fact that you have that module installed is completely irrelevant: you should ensure that the module is added to the pyinstaller bundle.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are creating the `.exe` with `pyinstaller`, try:

```
pyinstaller YOUR_FILE.py --hidden-import openpyxl.cell._writer
```

It lets `pyinstaller` know that `openpyxl.cell._writer` must be imported. It seems like this module import is done in a "hidden" way in your Python script. Therefore, it is not visible for `pyinstaller` and must be mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

downgrade openpyxl to version 3.0.9 might also help. it works for me.

```
pip uninstall openpyxl
pip install openpyxl==3.0.9
```