PyInstaller isn't working like it once did; executables are much larger and do not function; libraries and hidden imports not found?
I tried to reinstall Spyder IDE on my Windows operating system after a number of problems with my old 2023 copy of Spyder.
With the old Spyder, I used this script:
import PyInstaller.__main__
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
#import easygui

root1 = Tk()
root1.title("File Importer")       
root1.filenames = filedialog.askopenfilename\
(initialdir = "\\", title = "Select file to be imported.",
filetypes = [("all files","*.*")])
        
root1.destroy() 
    
print(root1.filenames)
  
file = root1.filenames
root1 = Tk()

folder = filedialog.askdirectory() 
root1.destroy()
print (folder) 
#imports = easygui.enterbox('List any hidden imports')
PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    '--onefile',
    f'--distpath={folder}',
#    f'--hidden-import={imports}' ,
    f'{file}',
])

Code pertaining to "hidden imports" has been 'commented out' because it proved unnecessary for producing functioning executables.
Now when I run the PyInstaller script in Spyder, the IPython Console shows the following messages:
C:/Users/USER/Python Scripts/my_program.py
INFO: PyInstaller: 6.11.1, contrib hooks: 2024.10
INFO: Python: 3.11.10 (conda)
INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
INFO: Python environment: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime
INFO: wrote c:\users\USER\documents\python scripts\converter_script\my_program.spec
C:/Users/USER_NAME/Python Scripts/
INFO: Module search paths (PYTHONPATH):
['C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime',
 '',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\_vendor',
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\\Documents\\Python Scripts,
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\\Documents\\Python Scripts,
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\\Documents\\Python Scripts,
 'C:\\Users\\USER\\\Documents\\Python Scripts]
INFO: checking Analysis
INFO: Building because c:\users\USER_NAME\documents\python scripts\converter_script\build\my_program\base_library.zip changed
INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-03.toc
INFO: Target bytecode optimization level: 0
INFO: Reusing cached module dependency graph...
INFO: Initializing module graph hook caches...
INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\python311.dll
INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\\my_program.py
INFO: Processing pre-find-module-path hook 'hook-tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-psutil.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-typing_extensions.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-jaraco.text.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Setuptools: 'jaraco.text' appears to be a setuptools-vendored copy - creating alias to 'setuptools._vendor.jaraco.text'!
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing pre-find-module-path hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-more_itertools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-jaraco.functools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-zipp.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-importlib_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-importlib_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-tomli.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-wheel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-setuptools._vendor.jaraco.text.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-jaraco.context.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-backports.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-backports.tarfile.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-platformdirs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-platformdirs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-gi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-matplotlib.pyplot.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backend_bases.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing pre-safe-import-module hook 'hook-six.moves.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-astroid.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-wcwidth.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-parso.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-docutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-sphinx.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-zoneinfo.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-jsonschema_specifications.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-yapf_third_party.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-shelve.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-cloudpickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-openpyxl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pandas.io.clipboard.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-qtpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: hook-qtpy: selected 'PyQt5' as Qt bindings because hook for 'PyQt5' has been run before.
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-selenium.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-pyodbc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing module hooks (post-graph stage)...
WARNING: Hidden import "charset_normalizer.md__mypyc" not found!
WARNING: Hidden import "importlib_resources.trees" not found!
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Matplotlib backend selection method: automatic discovery of used backends
INFO: Found configured default matplotlib backend: module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline
INFO: Selected matplotlib backends: ['module://matplotlib_inline.backend_inline']
15128290 INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
WARNING: Hidden import "scipy.special._cdflib" not found!
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
WARNING: Hidden import "pysqlite2" not found!
WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-psycopg2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
WARNING: Hidden import "mx.DateTime" not found!
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-tzdata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\stdhooks'
INFO: Performing binary vs. data reclassification (5994 entries)
INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_inspect.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgutil.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_cryptography_openssl.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\rthooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_traitlets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\rthooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks'
INFO: Processing pre-find-module-path hook 'hook-_pyi_rth_utils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path'
INFO: Processing standard module hook 'hook-_pyi_rth_utils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks'
INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks'
INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): []
INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): []

WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'impi.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Library\\bin\\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.2.dll'.
WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'ur_loader.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Library\\bin\\omptarget.rtl.unified_runtime.dll'.
WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'msmpi.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Library\\bin\\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.2.dll'.
WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'pgc.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Library\\bin\\mkl_pgi_thread.2.dll'.
WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'pgf90.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Library\\bin\\mkl_pgi_thread.2.dll'.
WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'pgmath.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Library\\bin\\mkl_pgi_thread.2.dll'.
WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'impi.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Library\\bin\\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.2.dll'.
WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'msmpi.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\spyder-6\\envs\\spyder-runtime\\Library\\bin\\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.2.dll'.

INFO: Warnings written to c:\users\USER\documents\python scripts\converter_script\build\my_program\warn-my_program.txt

INFO: Graph cross-reference written to c:\users\USER\documents\python scripts\converter_script\build\my_program\xref-my_program.html
INFO: checking PYZ
INFO: Building because toc changed
INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) c:\users\USER_NAME\documents\python scripts\converter_script\build\my_program\PYZ-03.pyz
INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) c:\users\USER\documents\python scripts\converter_script\build\my_program\PYZ-03.pyz completed successfully.
INFO: checking PKG
INFO: Building because toc changed
INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) my_program.pkg
INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) my_program.pkg completed successfully.
INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\run.exe
INFO: checking EXE
INFO: Rebuilding EXE-03.toc because my_program.exe missing
INFO: Building EXE from EXE-03.toc
INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python Scripts\\my_program.exe
INFO: Copying icon to EXE
INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
INFO: Fixing EXE headers
INFO: Building EXE from EXE-03.toc completed successfully.

In these Console messages, two sorts of messages concern me. I don't know if any of them appeared before with the old Spyder, so I don't know if they're the source of my problems now.
Regarding the Hidden Imports, I attempted to download each module to resolve the problem.
But only needed downloading. The first three were already downloaded.
The last three failed to download. Example:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysqlite2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pysqlite2

I have no idea how to resolve the 'not found' libraries.
What I do know is that every copy of the resulting .exe file is SIX TIMES as large as the ones I was originally producing, and none of them function.
When I open those executables, they do not generate the GUI window, and their command prompt window displays the following message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_program.py", line 9, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_write_only.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\\worksheet\\_writer.py", line 23, in init openpyxl.worksheet._writer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.cell._writer'
[PYI-21544:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'my_program' due to unhandled exception!

Here is the code in my_program that deals with openpyxl:
from pandas import ExcelWriter

with ExcelWriter(output_file_namePath, engine='openpyxl', mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists="overlay") as eWriter:
                    chunk_output_df1.to_excel(eWriter, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=allRow, header=False, index=False)
                    chunk_output_df2.to_excel(eWriter, sheet_name='Sheet2', startrow=fullRow+1, header=False, index=False)
                    allRow += thread_num
                    fullRow += chunk_output_df2.shape[0]


A coworker who is using a copy of my original PyInstaller-based script has shared his IPython Console messages with me, and he also gets the "missing imports" warnings while still producing functional executables. So it seems that is not the problem.

I am no longer getting warnings about unfound, unresolved libraries. Possibly because I removed all paths from Spyder's Environment Variable Paths and from PYTHONPATH. Despite that, my console still says it is searching those multiple paths at "INFO: Module search paths (PYTHONPATH):". My coworker's editor searches only one.

As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74926850/how-to-solve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-openpyxl-cell-writer, un-"commenting-out" the "--hidden-import={imports}" line, and setting the value to "openpyxl.cell._writer" solves that one problem, but doesn't explain why it wasn't a problem before. But all of my attempts so far to list multiple hidden imports have failed.

The way to declare multiple hidden imports is to declare "hidden-import=value" more than once. The user-interface provided in the example pyinstaller-using script at the start of the question post is insufficient for this task. You would be better off directly altering the contents of the "PyInstaller.main.run" code-block.
